# delete dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following code which I use to add text-boxes dynamically on click of button. It works.

```
<div id="forms" name="forms">
  <input name="winner[]" type="text" id="tag" size="20"/><br/>
</div>
<input type="button" name="addmore" id="addmore" value="Add More Winners" onclick="addForm()"/>
```

The javascript for the above code is:

```
function addForm() {
    $("#forms").append(
            "<input type ='text' class='winner' name='winner[]'><br/>");

    $(".winner").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true
    });
}
```

I am using auto complete to get data from database in the text-box

What I want is - suppose if a user clicks on add more winner button but does not want to add any data in the textbox, I should give him a button to delete the extra text-box.
How should the JavaScript be written for this?

Do see my above code

Answer (score 1):

```
var i=0;    
function addForm() {
    i++;
   $("#forms").append(
"<input type ='text' id='input_'"+i+" class='winner' name='winner[]'><button    onclick='delete('"+i+"')' id='button_'"+i+">delete</button><br/>");

$(".winner").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
selectFirst: true
});

function delete(i)
{
    $("#input_"+i).remove();
    $("#button_"+i).remove();

}
```

simply use a counter to set an ID to inputs and buttons and send that counter to delete function;

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the code below :

```
   $("#forms").append("<p><input type ='text' class='winner' name='winner[]' ><button onclick='$(this).parent().remove()'>delete</button></p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
function removeElement()
{
if(intTextBox != 0)
{
var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText'+intTextBox));
intTextBox = intTextBox-1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a remove button while adding a text box dynamically to remove the text box if necessary

Here is the html code

```
    <div id="forms" name="forms">
      <input name="winner[]" type="text" id="tag" size="20"/><br/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="addmore" id="addmore" value="Add More Winners" />
```

Here is the jQuery code

```
    $('#addmore').click(function () {
        $('#forms').append('<input type ="text" class="winner" name="winner[]"><input type="button" onclick="$(this).prev().remove();$(this).remove();">');
    });
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dGPW9/1/)